# High contrast shaders

Tags: shader, terrain

I found a shader on the NVidia site that looked nice but didn't provide me with what I wanted.

Here is an image:
[image]

The problem is, This little "bump" is made up of a ton of triangles, are there any free shaders that provide more contrast between the different triangles?
[image]

Comment: What are you talking about? I don't see a ton of triangles, I see a few. And what "contrast"? Color, height? What's the shader supposed to do?

Comment: @El Marcel, The second image shows defining lines that I went back in with a photo editing program to show.  See, you can't tell that there are a bunch of triangles.  I just need a shader that will distinguish one polygon face from another.

Comment: Why not render a wireframe on top of it?